# Material-UI Lists Not Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, material-ui

I'd like to create a post and have the post rendered in a list of the index page. When I'm on the index page, I press the 'Add Post' button, which will direct me to the `/posts/new` route. I then type into the input fields and submit the post. The posts are successfully being created, but the list is not rendering in the index page. I'm also not getting any errors. Is my renderPosts method of the PostsIndex component correct? Kindly point me in the right direction. Thank you!

NETWORK

[image]

ROOT INDEX

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import PostsIndex from "./containers/PostsIndex";
import PostsNew from "./containers/PostsNew";
import PostsShow from './containers/PostsShow';
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import promise from "redux-promise";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/posts/new" component={PostsNew} />
                    <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
                    <Route path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

APP

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import PostsIndex from './containers/PostsIndex';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <PostsIndex />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

POSTS INDEX

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts } from "../actions/index";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import _ from "lodash";

class PostsIndex extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    renderPosts = () => {
        return _.map(this.props.post, post => {
            return (
                <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
                    <List>
                        <ListItem key={post.id}>
                            <ListItemText primary={post.title}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Link>
            );
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Blog About It</h1>
                <Link to="/posts/new">Add Post</Link>
                <List>
                    <ul>{this.renderPosts()}</ul>
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchPosts }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PostsIndex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment so have to just try and answer,

The `renderPosts` uses `this.props.post` but it looks like it shpuld be `this.props.posts` as defined by your `mapStateToProps` method.

Comment: Good eye! Thank you!